# Undertow access log skipping time (%D)

Tags: spring-boot, undertow, access-log

I'm Configuring access log format for undertow.
what I configured in application.properties is this

```
server.undertow.accesslog.pattern=%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %s %b %D
```

But i'm gettin a "-" in place of %D

example

```
127.0.0.1 - - [26/Feb/2021:11:11:26 +0530] "POST /********/payments/token HTTP/1.1" 200 2529 -
```

Am i missing something

Answer (score 0):

If you start undertow with Spring Boot, the properties are

```
server.undertow.options.server.record-request-start-time=true
server.undertow.accesslog.pattern=[...] %T
```

[similar problem here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53098102/access-log-pattern-for-response-time-undertow-system-wildfly-14-0-1)